# Why is PowerShell's calling function not receiving the proper object type?

Tags: powershell, powercli

I am using VMware PowerCLI to perform some stuff with virtual machines in a PowerShell module with PowerShell 7.1.3. I am seeing some weird behavior with object types. Here's a rundown of what I'm doing:

Parent-Function.ps1:

```
function Parent-Function {
    $osCustomizationSpec = Child-Function -Name "AUTODEPLOY-ExampleConfiguration"
    Write-Verbose -Message $osCustomizationSpec.GetType()
}
```

This prints `System.Object[]` to the verbose stream

Child-Function.ps1:

```
function Child-Function {
    param([Parameter][string]$Name)

    $osCustomizationSpec = Get-OSCustomizationSpec -Name $Name
    Write-Verbose -Message $osCustomizationSpec.GetType()
    return $osCustomizationSpec
}
```

This prints `VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.VIObjectImpl` to the verbose stream

Basically, why is the calling function receiving the object as an array of System.Objects, when it's supposed to be returned as a `VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.VIObjectImpl` object?

Comment: Your `Child-Function` is actually returning an `object[]`. Position 0 of the function call will be the type returned by `Get-OSCustomizationSpec` and Position 1 will be the object returned by `Get-OSCustomizationSpec`.

Comment: Sorry, this was just sample code, and I'm actually wrapping the GetType() output with Write-Verbose. I've corrected the code now.

Comment: First, `Write-Verbose` prints to the information stream not stdout. Second, `Write-Verbose` won't print anything without `-Verbose` and `[cmdletbinding()]`. I feel like we are missing some relevant information to your answer.

Comment: You're correct in that it doesn't print to stdout. That was a vestige of the earlier sample code there. I understand that verbose is a different stream. This was the product of me trying to dumb down the sample code, while not realizing that something else was happening in the real code. See my response on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because PowerShell returns all output. You’re returning `.GetType()` then a return. PowerShell will collect that in an an array.

If you return 1 object you’ll get a scalar value of the given type. Return more than 1 object and you’ll get an array.

If those `.GetType()` calls are for debugging. Front them with Write-Host like:

`Write-Host ( $osCustomizationSpec).GetType().FullName`

That will write to the console not the output stream.

Comment: Sorry, this was just sample code, and I was actually wrapping the GetType() output using Write-Verbose. I've corrected the code now.

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted, because it helped me figure this out. It got me looking in debug mode, and I saw that the System.Object array did contain the proper type in the second index, only because I found that I was mistakenly returning something else earlier in the real code. PowerShell can be tricky in terms of seeing exactly what is returned sometimes if you're coming from a more structured language like C#.

Comment: @RootHouston You can return multiple objects of different types in PS functions. In your first code snippet, if you were to save the result of your function like `$result = Child-Function -Name 'something'` then `$result[0]` would have displayed the object type returned by the cmdlet `Get-OSCustomizationSpec` and `$result[1]` would have contained the actual object returned by the cmdlet. That's what I meant in my comment. So `$result[0] = object` and `$result[1] = object` so `$result = object[]`